Can I use template parameters to refer to base class member functions?
I'm trying to understand why this code doesn't compile with GCC but compiles with MSVC:
template<class TParams>
class Selector : public TParams::DataSource1, public TParams::DataSource2
{
    using DataSource1 = typename TParams::DataSource1;
    using DataSource2 = typename TParams::DataSource2;

public:
    template<class Fn>
    static void ForEachDataSource(Fn && fn)
    {
        fn.template operator()<DataSource1>();
        fn.template operator()<DataSource2>();
    }

    void Select(int i)
    {
        ForEachDataSource([&, this]<typename T>()
        {
            this->T::Query(i);
        });
    }
};

https://godbolt.org/z/bnv9jcYEe
The class Selector is inherited from multiple classes which provide member function Query. Selector::Select then calls Query from each of the base classes. I've decided to move iteration into a separate function so that I wouldn't need to duplicate logic for each of the base classes.
The code above fails to compile with GCC with the following error:
error: 'T' is not a class or namespace
   36 |             this->T::Query(i);

In my understanding T is class DataSource1 in this context and there should be no errors.
Ok, what if we omit this->?
ForEachDataSource([&, this]<typename T>()
{
    T::Query(i);
});

In my understanding, the code is also OK because T refers to one of the base classes, but
MSVC doesn't agree with me on this one:
error C2352: 'DataSourceF::Query': a call of a non-static member function requires an object

Explicitly casting this to one of the base classes works in all compilers but requires some detection to support both const and non-const qualified functions.
static_cast<T *>(this)->Query(i); // What if `this` is `const`?

Note that calling Query directly also works in all compilers regardless of used method:
this->DataSource1::Query(i);
DataSource2::Query(i);

Does the standard prohibits using template parameters to refer to base classes when calling their member functions? Which compiler is correct in this case?

Yes, you can use template parameters to refer to base class member functions. std::invoke is a helper function for such purposes.
Replace this->T::Query(i); with
std::invoke(&T::Query, this, i);

https://godbolt.org/z/nx5x6KGfK
This is equivalent of the code below that can be compiled by all mentioned compilers.
(this->*&T::Query)(i);

